# What kind of Room am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I am a kind of Room

But people cannot stay inside me.

People can put some of us inside them.

For the rest of us, we don't recommend to put me in you.

I am not a washroom, yet I have lot of water.

Who am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a

> Mushroom

I am a kind of Room

> mushROOM - there is a wordplay tag

But people cannot stay inside me.

> Mushrooms are too small

People can put some of us inside them.

> Some are edible

For the rest of us, we don't recommend to put me in you.

> Some are poisonous

I am not a washroom, yet I have lot of water.

> Mushrooms have about 90% water content

Comment: Thats really FAST!!!!!!!!! I want to accept it but the website says me to wait 5 more minutes to wait.

Answer (score 2):

You could be a

> Cell

Because

> A cell is a kind of a room - in a prison or monastery, for example

But

> A cell is also a microscopic portion of a plant, animal, or microbe. You cannot live inside of one of these cells - they are far too small - but you can eat some of them (edible things) while others are toxic/poisonous.

Comment: Nice attempt :)